# Javascript traversing tables to get values in the first list

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm trying to traverse this line of codes through xpath javascript, but I can't seem to get the value of the first li tag, which is Thesis [Master's) -- University, 2012.":

```
<table id="addInformationGraphics" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<TR><td background="/images/icons/general/thickline.gif" nowrap vAlign='top'>
<span class='ColRow'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="SectionHeader" ><a name = 'anchorAdditionalInfo'></a>
Additional Info
</span>
</td>
<A name="AdditionalInfo"></A></TR></TABLE>
<table id="addInformation" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td vAlign="top"><IMG SRC="/images/icons/general/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1"></td>
<td class="ColRow"><ul><li>
 Thesis [Master&#39;s) -- University, 2012.</li></ul>     
</td>
</tr>
```

Here's one of those I'm trying:

```
  var getaddInformation = document.evaluate("table[contains(@id,'addInformation')]/tbody/tr/td/following- sibling::td/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
if (getaddInformation.singleNodeValue) {
var addInformationDetails = getaddInformation.singleNodeValue.textContent;
       }
console.log(addInformationDetails);
    var getaddInformation = document.evaluate("table[contains(@id,'addInformationGraphics')]/following-sibling::table/td/following-sibling::td/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
if (getaddInformation.singleNodeValue) {
  var addInformationDetails = getaddInformation.singleNodeValue.textContent;
               }
console.log(addInformationDetails);
```

And another one:

```
var getaddInformation = document.evaluate("table[contains(@id,'addInformationGraphics')]/following-sibling::table/td/following-sibling::td/ul/li", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );
if (getaddInformation.singleNodeValue) {
  var addInformationDetails = getaddInformation.singleNodeValue.textContent;
       }
console.log(addInformationDetails);
```

For simplicity's sake, here's the xpath:

```
"table[contains(@id,'addInformation')]/tbody/tr/td/following-sibling::td/ul/li
And the other one:
 table[contains(@id,'addInformationGraphics')]/following-sibling::table/td/following-sibling::td/ul/li
```

What could be I'm missing, if I'm not mistaken, the hierarchy of the HTML doc is something like below:

```
table 
  tbody 
    tr 
      td
      td
        ul
        li
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A path starting with `table` and an API using `document` as the context node would only select that element if the root element of the document is a `table` element. An HTML document usually has a `html` root element and `table`s are descendants of the `body` child so depending on your structure you either want to pass in `document.body` as the second argument of all `evaluate` calls or you need `/html/body/table` as the XPath (for `table` children of the `body` element) or `/html/body//table` (for descendant `table` elements of the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `evaluate` API, the second argument is the context node, so, if you want to find a HTML `table` in an HTML document you usually use `document.body` with a relative path like `table` to find `table` children of the `body`:

```js
var getaddInformation = document.evaluate("table[contains(@id,'addInformation')]/tbody/tr/td/ul/li", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );

if (getaddInformation.singleNodeValue) {
  var addInformationDetails = getaddInformation.singleNodeValue.textContent;
  console.log(addInformationDetails);
}
```

```html
<table id="addInformationGraphics" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<TR><td background="/images/icons/general/thickline.gif" nowrap vAlign='top'>
<span class='ColRow'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="SectionHeader" ><a name = 'anchorAdditionalInfo'></a>
Additional Info
</span>
</td>
<A name="AdditionalInfo"></A></TR></TABLE>
<table id="addInformation" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td vAlign="top"><IMG SRC="/images/icons/general/spacer.gif" width="20" height="1"></td>
<td class="ColRow"><ul><li>
 Thesis [Master&#39;s) -- University, 2012.</li></ul>     
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or you need to change the XPath to start with e.g. `/html/body/table` or `//table`.

Note however that asking for the "first" list and using `XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE` is not going to give a consistent result, if you are looking for something based on document order then use `FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing context node (document.body), I was able to  traverse my document. The xpath is: //table[contains(@id,'addInformation')]//td/following-sibling::td//li.